# How to detect Connection Lost from WCF Service in client app

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, connection

How do I get a Lost Connection Exception from WCF in a client application.

At the time of the Fault, the exception in my Locals windows i get a $exception, but i can't use that exception.

Comment: It would be useful to see your code?

Comment: There is no permanent, or held connection to a WCF web service. There is only a connection when you attempt to use it, so you can detect that there is no connection when you attempt to use it, but get an `Exception` instead of your expected results.

Comment: When your callback is taking more time as compared to the timeout specified by your proxy then you get timeout exceptions. Share the code you use to catch the exceptions of the callback.

Answer (score 0):

If using WPF try to handle the **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException**.
You can check the type of exception from EventArgs, and create your logic there.